# Devise says 'Password Can't be Blank' on a API request - Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I'm trying to create a new user with Devise, using Rails API. However, when you do an URL request it says "Password can't be blank", while on Rails console it works fine. Below are some information about the controller and the request. What am I doing wrong?

Controller:

```
class Api::ClientsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    def index
        render json: Client.all
    end
    def show
        client = Client.find(params[:id])
        render json: client
    end
    def create
        client = Client.new(client_params)
        if client.save!
            head 200
        else
            head 500
        end
    end
    private
    def client_params
        params.require("client").permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Curl Request:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"oi", "email":"oi2@gmail.com","password":"123456", "password_confirmation":"123456"}' http://localhost:3000/api/clients
```

Server Response:

```
  Processing by Api::ClientsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"name"=>"oi", "email"=>"oi2@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "client"=>{"name"=>"oi", "email"=>"oi2@gmail.com"}}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/api/clients_controller.rb:12
  Client Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "oi2@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/clients_controller.rb:12
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/api/clients_controller.rb:12
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Password can't be blank):
app/controllers/api/clients_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

Comment: You are not passing the password inside the 'client' key as your `client_params` expect: `"client"=>{"name"=>"oi", "email"=>"oi2@gmail.com"}`

Comment: I thought it was because, Email and name has been accepted, except for the password. I will test this aproach with the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CURL request seems incorrect.

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"oi", "email":"oi2@gmail.com","password":"123456", "password_confirmation":"123456"}' http://localhost:3000/api/clients
```

This does not put the client attributes under `client` as expected. Try this instead:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"client":{"name":"oi", "email":"oi2@gmail.com","password":"123456", "password_confirmation":"123456"}}' http://localhost:3000/api/clients
```

Comment: Thank you, but it gives the following err:
ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError (743: unexpected token at '{client:{"name":"oi", "email":"oi2@gmail.com","password":"123456", "password_confirmation":"123456"}}'):

Comment: Refresh my answer, I fixed it (missing quotes around "client")

Comment: Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:

ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError (743: unexpected token at '{client:{"name":"oi", "email":"oi2@gmail.com","password":"123456", "password_confirmation":"123456"}}'):

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is with nesting since Rails param already does this job, and it's currently also accepting name and email, except for the password

Comment: Have you tried with '{"client":{"name":"oi", "email":"oi2@gmail.com","password":"123456", "password_confirmation":"123456"}}'